# How to remove an extra hline in beamerouterthememiniframes?

Tags: beamer

I have an extra two hlines in my header from the miniframes package that I can't identify a source for. They can be seen in the attached picture as very light blue lines immediately below "Section 1" and above "Title 1" outlining the subsection box. I can't find where their color is defined, what object they are or even any documentation online about the existence of these lines (admittedly, googling miniframes.sty is not particularly helpful on this front).

I have checked [beamerouterthememiniframes.sty](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthememiniframes.sty) and guess-and-checked removing parts of the headline block at the bottom. I suspect the line is either

1. Coming from something I don't understand with \insertsectionhead
2. An artifact to do with colorboxes, though I haven't found any reference to that in the literature either

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\definecolor{betterblue}{RGB}{49,114,174}
\definecolor{accessibleblue}{RGB}{52,96,148}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=betterblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=accessibleblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=accessibleblue}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title 1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two extra hlines of undefined color below section 1 and above Title 1]

EDIT: Here is a picture of the line in acrobat reader where it has been claimed such a line does not exist. The failure of such a line to exist in chrome actually seems to be a persistent kind of problem there ([source 1](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1095), [source 2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35796&q=dasharray&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)). For the four of you who voted to close -- this might well be a beamerbox issue which is well within the parameters for this site. It might also be an OS issue, but there's not evidence for that yet either. A reference to an open bug would certainly be an answer.

[image: The line in adobe]

Comment: That is for subsections and/or the circles representing frames.

Comment: @Symbol1 you mean `insertsubsectionhead` or do you mean the definition of miniframes? The hline above and below is persistent, even with `[subsection=false]` as an option for miniframes as an outer theme. The line even sticks around for a similar looking headline with the same insert commands...

Comment: If I have `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` then the line will not show up. Did you check for update?

Comment: There's a very thin light blue line between "Title 1" and "Section 1" regardless of the existence of the subsection block. It's actually in the given picture as well but it's subtle. I can't find a source for the color of that line, but would like for it to not be there. I'm going to edit the initial question to try to make that more clear, because it's not obvious there.

Comment: I suspect that the thin light blue line is a renderer issue. LaTeX can barely help at such aspect.

Comment: Hm. The line appears clearly in Skim, Preview, Safari and the TeXShop pdf viewer. The only place it _does not_ appear is in the chrome pdf viewer. I have no idea what to make of that.

Comment: That's a viewer issue where the beamerboxes touch each other. It's not visible in adobe reader. Preview and similar readers are known to have problems with such things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issue with some pdf viewers

Comment: @samcarter do you have a source for the claim that "Preview and similar readers are known to have problems with such things"? Finding such a source would be an appropriate answer (while closing the question with no source is probably against community objectives)

Comment: @SethRothschild For example https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1824971?start=0&tstart=0 discusses the issue with preview. Of course if you zoom in to 3200% you can make it appear in any viewer, as adjoining shapes are tricky for pdf viewers, see for example http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches